# Is it possible to slice a dictionary like a list (based on index)?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, slice

I want to create a new dictionary based on an old one. The items I want to include are from a specific index order to another specific index order.

I saw that there are a lot of answers about peeking the items based on values or keys, this is not what I'm looking for.
I have this dict that sits in a pandas DataFrame in a specific row, the dict includes tuple for the key and Id for the value:

```py
{(24, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:20:48')): '77034', (25, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:21:47')): '77034', (26, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:31:25')): '77034', (27, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:32:11')): '77034', (53, Timestamp('1900-01-01 13:22:51')): '77034', (54, Timestamp('1900-01-01 13:30:40')): '77034', (57, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:28:25')): '77034', (58, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:29:32')): '77034', (59, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:43:55')): '77034', (60, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:44:46')): '77034', (70, Timestamp('1900-01-01 16:56:44')): '77034', (71, Timestamp('1900-01-01 16:57:41')): '77034', (72, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:02:57')): '77034', (73, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:33:29')): '19975', (74, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:43:56')): '14145', (77, Timestamp('1900-01-01 19:23:26')): '77034'}
```

So far I used a dict comprehension that produced nothing.

I want to be able to get something like this:

```py
for row in df.itertuples():
    df.at[row.Index, 'dict_by_index'] = row.full_dict[13:14]
```

This will produce a new dict in a new column in the dataframe:
`{(73, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:33:29')): '19975', (74, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:43:56')): '14145'}`

Comment: dictionary doesn't have the concept of indexes, only a list does, but you can select a list of dicitionaries from a bigger list using slicing, which you are doing here I think

Comment: Also note that the order of a dictionary is not guaranteed before Python 3.7.

Comment: thanks for the comments. i solved it with a bit of a workaround but it answered my problem. first i converted the dict to list and sliced it: `matchList = list(row.full_dict.items())[14:16]`. then flip it back to dict: `matchList = dict(matchList)`. now i need to append it back to the DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

you can use this instead:

```py
df = [{(24, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:20:48')): '77034'}, {(25, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:21:47')): '77034'}, {(26, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:31:25')): '77034'}, {(27, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:32:11')): '77034'}, {(53, Timestamp('1900-01-01 13:22:51')): '77034'}, {(54, Timestamp('1900-01-01 13:30:40')): '77034'}, {(57, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:28:25')): '77034'}, {(58, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:29:32')): '77034'}, {(59, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:43:55')): '77034'}, {(60, Timestamp('1900-01-01 15:44:46')): '77034'}, {(70, Timestamp('1900-01-01 16:56:44')): '77034'}, {(71, Timestamp('1900-01-01 16:57:41')): '77034'} , {(72, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:02:57')): '77034'} , {(73, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:33:29')): '19975'} , {(74, Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:43:56')): '14145'} , {(77, Timestamp('1900-01-01 19:23:26')): '77034'}]
```

basically i made all of this inside a `[]` and then divided every one into an independent object, so right now, it's an list not a dictionary anymore, and as long as its a list, it will work with indexes

now try do:

```py
print(df[0])
```

and it will print the first object, which is

```py
{(24, Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:20:48')): '77034'}
```

you can do `df[1]` or `df[2]` and so on, now that this work with indexes, you should be good to go.

Hope this Helps.